# Julian date (YYYYDDD) to YYYYMMDD Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, date

there is surprisingly little on the internet on converting a date that's in the Julian format YYYYDDD to YYYYMMDD. Does anyone know how to do it in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 0):

You can use to_date()

```
select to_date('2020123', 'yyyyddd')
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=5b1eb837630f00c08c51c18f3fe40b01)